# Unable to change background color using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table in which I have numeric boxes and few of them have already a value of 0 when page loads.

I want to change the background color of those boxes in which value is 0 when page loads. below is the code I am using but its not working for me, please suggest.

```
if($('tr td').children('input').val()==0)
                      $(this).css('background-color','#cccccc');
```

Comment: can you put your html +  some more detailed code?

Comment: We don't even know what $(this) is referring to as you didn't put the complete code.. This code itself shows nothing

Comment: @Neel Please find the complete html below.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DXQ5j/

Comment: @DominicTobias Please find the link above.

Answer (score 0):

here you go(using jquery version 1.11):

```
 $('table tr td').each(function() {

        if ($(this).text()==='0'){

            $(this).css('background-color', 'black');}
     });
```

working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3He4q/1/

Comment: Can I use .val() also? I think ==== operator checks the exact specified value. @learner420

Comment: val() is used only for those element which have a 'value' attribute associated with it. i.e, input tag. secondly it's === operator not ==== and its for the comparison with 'ZERO' which in your case apply.

Comment: Thanks. Can u pls take a look at my example and help on why it is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/DXQ5j/

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
$('tr td').each(function() {

        if ($(this).children("input").val() ==='0'){

            $(this).css('background-color', 'black');}
     });
    });
```

Demo :- http://jsfiddle.net/DXQ5j/1/

and you require to set the value as below :-

```
 for(var i=1;i<=6;i++)
    {
        $("#"+i).val(0);
    }
```

instead of

```
 for(var i=1;i<=6;i++)
    {
        $("#"+i).val()=0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can u also advise on why my code is not working.        http://jsfiddle.net/DXQ5j/

Comment: you have changed the code at wrong place see my updated ans + you need a loop which is not there in your code..compare your code with the fiddle I provided @Vaibhav

Comment: even after doing it your way my fiddle is not working :( http://jsfiddle.net/DXQ5j/5/ @Neel

Comment: you are missing brackets to close the document.ready + give '0' instead of 0 + give reffernce to jquery version for example 1.9.1

Comment: pleasure :) mark it as answer if you think its usefull @Vaibhav :)

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution, actually you have used the assignment operator val wrongly: 
Also the html part you have done was creepy :P.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        $("#" + i).val(0);
    }

  //  if ($('tr td').text()==='0'){ $(this).css('background-color', //'#cccccc');}
    $('input').each(function() {

        if ($(this).val()==='0'){

            $(this).css('background-color', 'black');}
     });   

});
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DXQ5j/7/

Answer (score 0):

Given the corrected HTML, I'd suggest the following approach:

```
// select all input elements, filter that collection:
$('input').filter(function(){
    // keep only those input elements whose value is equal to 0:
    return 0 === parseInt(this.value,10);
// select the closest ancestor 'td' element:
}).closest('td')
// set the background-color of those 'td' elements:
.css('background-color','black');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DXQ5j/8/).

Although it would be slightly better to use `addClass()` then the colour can be more-easily changed, and unchanged:

```
$('input').filter(function(){
    return 0 === parseInt(this.value,10);
}).closest('td').addClass('zeroValueInput');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DXQ5j/9/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        for(var i=1;i<=6;i++)
    {
```

> $("#"+i).val()=0;

//Mistake: use assignment like you have used in the if condition below  i.e. $("#"+i).val(0);

> if($('tr td').children('input').val(0))

//mistake: "This is assignment and return if success". Not Comparison.

> $(this).css('background-color','#cccccc');

//mistake: how can you be so sure that "this" will contain the required element's reference? use each operator like the other posts have used.

```
    });
```